# Click web button using name

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, webbrowser-control

```
Set HTMLDoc = WebBrowser1.document.frames("top").document
HTMLDoc.forms("Nav").GetCase.Click
```

This was my vb6 code to click a button within a form using HTMLDOC as mshtml.document.  How do I do this in vb.net?  I need to specify exactly whether to use mshtml or the windows system browser.document when executing as well. html is below:

```
 <form name = "Nav"> 'just for reference
<input name="GetCase" style="font: 7pt arial;" onclick="if(!getCase()){return;};" type="button" size="1" value="Retrieve"/>
```

Comment: Is it important you show the document to the user, or are you just taking advantage of the web browser control to scrape a site? If the latter, .Net has some nicer tools to use for web scraping (see system.net.webclient,httpwebrequest,httpwebresponse)

Comment: im trying to input a value into a text field and click a submit button, to pull up an intranet page.  They will need to access the page through the control.   this will just pull addresses (eventually) from the page and automate labeling. htmldoc takes a snapshot of the page and then you sift through the elements essentially I used this before in vb6: `Set HTMLDoc = CAS.document.frames("top").document //HTMLDoc.forms("NavPage").ContractNum.Value = variablenum /// HTMLDoc.forms("Nav").GetCase.Click`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 myBrowser.Document.GetElementById("GetCase").InvokeMember("click");
```

assume GetCase is unique. bascially, mshtml can do much more than .net web browser.

Comment: GetCase is unique. I tried the above as well, it returns "Object variable or With block variable not set". This used to happen when i did not specify the exact frame which is at axWebBrowser1.document.frames("top").document.  New to .net, when I try specifying that with invoke member it errors out still.

Comment: see above change. did you wait the document_complete?

Comment: Yes, I wait until the document completes, and this is being started from a button click and stepped through.  I got the same "obj variable or with block variable not set", probably because there is no id for that field.

If i dimension a as object and do 

`a = AxWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByName("GetCase")`

It does return back 0, which is where i need to click, just unsure, since you cannot do a.click or a.invoke member

Comment: I tried: 'Dim allelements As HtmlElementCollection = AxWebBrowser1.Document 'For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In allelements ' If webpageelement.GetAttribute("value") = "Retrieve" Then ' webpageelement.InvokeMember("click") ' End If 'Next //// but it needs a clear definition between mshtml and the system.windows.forms version, since the two directly arent compatable

Comment: I got my answer, its:

 htmldoc.getElementsByName("GetCase")(0).click()